# How to get the last cell information in Perl module Excel::Writer::XLSX?

Tags: perl, excel-2007, xlsx

I am using Perl module Excel::Writer::XLSX. How can I get the row number and column number for the last cell in the spreadsheet? I know in VB, it's something like ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell) to get the last cell.

Answer (score 1):

It can be accomplished easily with  [Spreadsheet::XLSX](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Spreadsheet%3a%3aXLSX)

From the example given in CPAN:

```
my $excel = Spreadsheet::XLSX -> new ('test.xlsx', $converter);

foreach my $sheet (@{$excel -> {Worksheet}}) 
{        
   $sheet -> {MaxRow}; # Returns row of last cell 
   $sheet -> {MaxCol}; # Returns column of last cell 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried Spreadsheet::XLSX before, and the problem for it is it is quite a simple module without a lot of cool functions I need. Maybe I should use it just for the Last Cell information. :S

Answer (score 1):

In Excel::Writer, you can use $sheet->{_dim_rowmax} to get the last row number. 
Similarly, the following codes able to help you to access the min and max row and columns.

```
$sheet->{_dim_rowmin}
$sheet->{_dim_colmax}
$sheet->{_dim_colmin}
```